# How to parallelize a recursive bash function?

Tags: bash, function, recursive, parallelism, gnu-parallel

I have a bash function that mainly `curl`s an endpoint for a set of links, and again curls each of those links (for another set of links) recursively.

```bsh
task() {
  link="$1"
  response=$(curl "$link")
  
  # save response data to file...

  # process response to find another set of links and save to variable x...
  if condition
      echo "$x" | while read -r link
        task "$link"
}
```

The above code yields to ~100 curl operations which take a long time. Mainly the endpoint's response time (not processing) is the bottleneck.

**Conditions**

1. We have 0 info about how many links are there. We can't have a child link without `curl`ing it parent link first.
2. Each response of `curl link` should be atomically saved to a file

Is it even possible to parallelize this procedure? I'm OK if the solution needs (or is more elegant with) `GNU parallel` or some other external tool.

Comment: Does each `curl` produce multiple child links (in which case they might be parallelizable), or just one (in which case they can only be sequential)? Also, if the network is the bottleneck, would parallelization actually help at all (since multiple simultaneous `curl`s will just compete for bandwidth)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson Each curl produces multiple links. By network, I meant the API's GET response time. I edit my post now.

Comment: External tools like GNU `parallel` or `xargs -P` won't work with a function (not directly, anyway - you could make it run `sh -c 'task ...'` with a .bashrc that defined the function) because the bash function only exists within the bash shell where it is defined.  They will work with scripts that implement the same function, same as they would with any other executable.    If you really want to do this with a function, you could just run the `task` function in the background with `&` but you'd have to write your own queueing code to limit the number of simultaneous tasks.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson says, though, since CPU isn't the bottleneck, parallelisation is unlikely to help and may even harm performance.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the breadth-first spider as a template: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-breadth-first-parallel-web-crawler-mirrorer